# Tumblr wrongly outputs audio posts in video post type

Tags: tumblr

<strike>On my blog</strike> I created [special tumblr blog (testcase)](http://audioinvideobug.tumblr.com/) for this bug, where i handle only two post types: video and text and have code my theme accordingly. In spite of this, Tumblr also displays audio posts, which are a [separate type of posts](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts) from video posts, how to fix this?

Here is a picture of a Spotify audio embed being displayed inside a video post block:
[wrong output for video&audio posts http://i.imm.io/pdu2.png](http://i.imm.io/pdu2.png)

Here is the [full markup on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/n3010tQH)

Some simple markup to test:

```
{block:Posts}
    <li> <article class="{PostType} {TagsAsClasses}">
    {block:Text}
        …
        <p><b>hardcoded post type: text</b></p>
        <p><b>tumblr post type: {PostType}</b></p>
    {/block:Text}

    {block:Video}
        …
        <p><b>hardcoded post type: video</b></p>
        <p><b>tumblr post type: {PostType}</b></p>
    {/block:Video}
    </article> </li>
{/block:posts}
```

The error is confirmed:

[image]

**Update:** I [duplicated](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/tumblr-themes/FfqJ9mjyFr0/discussion) this post about this bug in official tumblr themes [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ru&fromgroups#!forum/tumblr-themes) and wrote to tumblr support and my ticket number is **852138**

**Update 2:** [Special blog](http://audioinvideobug.tumblr.com/) for this bug created

**Update 3:** Tumblr answered:

> We will do our best to make sure the issue is resolved asap. Thank you very much for you consideration and understanding! (ticket 852138)
>
> I can't tell you how much we appreciate your support and feedback. I've passed your information along to our team. (ticket 852136)

There are two tickets, because I was surprised, when my first message to support have been cutted, so i sent second message with only link to this question.

Comment: Very odd. Could you link to the page the actual problem happens on, please?

Comment: I’ve had a look, and the API is returning correct post types (the Spotify embed is returned on `audio`, not on `video`), so the issue *is* located somewhere between the raw template and the processed HTML. Could you post the full code of the template somewhere and link to it here?

Comment: Try simplifying your template by making sure you only have one `{block:<postType>}` block token each – you will be able to get rid of a lot of redundant code, and it is worth the try two see if Tumblr’s engines serves post correctly when not confronted with multiple post type blocks. I’ve done [a quick Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rxEJUTTw) of your example code above after revision, to give you an idea of what I mean.

Comment: @kopischke with simplified markup error still exists

Comment: You might have discovered a *bona fide* bug in Tumblr’s templating engine. Have you tried contacting Tumblr support?

Comment: @matmuchrapana: support@tumblr.com – see http://www.tumblr.com/help/en (you might be redirected to your language, where that address is not present. One of Tumblr’s more stupid localization decisions). Be sure to post the result of your exchange with them here if it affects your question.

Comment: excellent – I’d be glad to hear of developments concerning your support ticket. This is a weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

Spotify embed is "always" video. But, tumblr wrote it as Audio post. If you want to made the spotify embed on the audio post, you need added this code in the {block:Audio} tags.

```
{block:AudioEmbed}{AudioEmbed}{/block:AudioEmbed}
```

hope it's helped you. :)

Comment: read more carefully: i have no `{block:Audio}` tags in my tumblr markup

Comment: so, it means you want to include spotify as video or hide "all" the audio post?

Comment: «i handle only two post types: video and text» I output in tumblr markup only video and audio, but suddenly audio appears in video section of my tumblr markup. Please reread question.